# Docusign|Salesforce In-Person Signing for iPhone

Tags: docusignapi

I understand that in-person signing is not supported by the Docusign publisher action in Salesforce1 due to a lack of screen rotation, however, it does seem to be supported by the Docusign iOS app for the iPhone.  I'm interested to see if there is a way around this limitation, potentially utilizing both apps.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a beta, opt-in feature in DocuSign for Salesforce that allows for launching the DocuSign iOS app rather than using the normal DocuSign Tagging/Sending screen.  You might be able to use that.

In Salesforce go to the DocuSign Admin tab, select Envelopes, go to the Send Setting section, and tick the "Enable DocuSign mobile app tagging for Salesforce1 (Beta)" tick box.

[image: Screen shot of DocuSign for Salesforce configuration]